# How to give a Table name in Entity Framework by code first approach in .Net Framework 4.0?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

In .NET 4.0 framework the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` doesn't work or doesn't support I think.

I am using a code-first approach and my database already exists, and also not using ADO.net Entity Data Model.

I already used the `[Table]` attribute and `DatabaseGenerated` attribute, it's not working causing a compilation error to occur.

This is my code:

Entity class:

```
public class myclass
{
    public myclass()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    [Key]
    public int RECORDID { get; set; }
    public string AA { get; set; }
    public string CAT { get; set; }
    public string CS { get; set; }
    public int? FS { get; set; }
    public int? CA { get; set; }
    public int? DR { get; set; }
    public int? UM { get; set; }
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public double LAT { get; set; }
    public double LON { get; set; }
    public int? NIC { get; set; }
}
```

`DbContext` class:

```
public class classContext : DbContext
{
    public classContext() : base("name=DBConnection")
    {
        //Disable initializer
        Database.SetInitializer<classContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<myclass> myclasses { get; set; }
}
```

Or I have to add this override method of model creating, is it helpful or not?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<myclass>().ToTable("Datatbl");
}
```

Help me out. Thanks

Comment: You can have a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Table attribute over your class:

```
[Table("Datatbl")]
public class myclass
{
}
```

Comment: #manoj : the table Attribute use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema namespace or i am using the 4.0

Comment: Yes it uses the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema

Comment: but its not there in the Reference library.